# Remove Link From Title/Remove Small Text From Header On One Wordpress Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i want to remove the link from my header using CSS so that only the text "my inner yoga" shows, but it is not a hyperlink. i tried to do

```
#post-28 .site-title.a {display:none;}
```

but it didnt work. i know it has to do with the site-title because i don't know how to say in CSS that i want to only have the "a" tag not working, but only in the site-title div.

also, is it possible to remove the "learn more" text from the right side of my header? i don't know PHP so that part is confusing to me. i dont know if its possible to do with css.

the link is: http://myinneryoga.com/strange-exotic-fruit-supplement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done with CSS, but you can just display the site title itself using

```
 <?php echo $bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

If you only want it removed on one page, use a conditional IF statement to query the page ID or slug and set a version without the site URL attached and an ELSE to set a version with the URL.

To remove the learn more text, add this code to the end of your functions.php file:

```
function improved_trim_excerpt($text) { // Fakes an excerpt if needed
global $post;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text, '<p>');
    $excerpt_length = 100;
    $words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
    if (count($words)> $excerpt_length) {
        array_pop($words);
        array_push($words, '');
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'improved_trim_excerpt');
```

If I'm correct the theme developer added a custom excerpt ending. Either that or it's just a hardcoded link, in which case go into the header file and use the find function of whatever editor you are using and search for the "learn more" text, then just remove it and the  tag around it.

Comment: this is way over my head right now. do you know any good tutorial websites that can teach me where i need to put this information or how to figure out where in my theme it needs to go?

Comment: The wordpress codex has all the codes you'd need:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

As for where to find it, I would assume it would be in the header.php file of the theme you are using.

Comment: would this be able to only remove the link ONLY this one page though? wont the header edit EVERY page?

Comment: That's why the IF statement is necessary. It will leave the link if the page ID isn't the one you specified to remove it for.

Comment: thanks corey, i'm trying to investigate this which is why i havent responded. i guess i had to learn php eventually if i was going to do this wordpress stuff lol

Comment: I barely know raw php myself, but I used to develop custom wordpress themes on a regular basis, which is much easier and also a good stepping stone because of how it allows you to call functions quickly and easily. Really helps ease you in to the mammoth task that lies ahead.

Comment: you wouldn't have to learn wordpress first, but if you do it will help you focus on what is needed and what some of the basic things do so when you attempt bigger and betters things all the php tags and coding won't scare you away.

Comment: no it is a widget box that goes in the top right corner, i added my link at the end of it, sorry for the confusion there

Comment: ok, you can try to use the same css trick to hide the link and text in that part of the header. having looked at the source code this should work in the css:

.widget-inside a{display:none;}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you're generating "Learn Now", but if it's just a link you should be able to do something like the following (let's say the post ID is 17).

```
<?php if (!is_single(17)) { ?>
    <a href="http://myinneryoga.com/about/">Learn More</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Like Corey said above, use `<?php echo $bloginfo('name'); ?>` to show the name. Remove any `<a>` tag that might be surrounding it.

Comment: the "learn now" is in a text widget that is the same for every page across the whole site, i only want it to disappear on this one page

Comment: Standard Wordpress text widgets won't let you use PHP, but [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-text-widget/) will enable it.

Comment: i dont understand what this code is saying. what is the !is_single(17) referring to? is that referring to the page i linked you to because i think the page id is 28 on it. or is that something else? so would i have to combine that if code with the code corey said also? thank you for any insights scottoliver.

Comment: edited my answer to remove the learn more text. try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: The "is_single" is a function in Wordpress that checks to see if the current page is a post. I didn't know what the post ID was so I made one up as an example. is_single(17) checks to see if it's the post with the ID 17. so if the page loaded is the post with ID #17, show the Learn More.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Modify style.css line 482

```
#site-title a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```